# How to parse a service in Apple Watch in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on Swift and I am new to Apple Watch Programming. I am making a demo app in iOS i.e displaying images on feed. To display the images, I have to parse a service.

I know how to implement it for iPhone, but I don’t understand how to implement it for Apple Watch, and even I don't know that it is possible on Apple Watch or not???

If it is not possible then how should I show the data from a service in Apple Watch??

Is there any other way to display the data in Apple Watch?

Can any one explain me about this clearly, please...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511601/download-images-in-a-table-in-watch-kit-async

Answer (score 0):

To consume web services on the Apple Watch you will need to use the `NSURLSession` API. You can also use an easy to use, popular framework called `AFNetworking`. This will make the requests and parse the data for you

Comment: Is it possible to use Alamofire??

Comment: Yes. That is the same. the AF in AFNetworking stands for AlamoFire

Comment: Yes, you can use Alamofire on WatchKit.

Comment: I added watchKit as a target  to my existing project and i use the statement "import Alamofire" in WAtchKit Extension InterfaceController.swift file. But it shows an error like no such module.

Comment: Any reference please.

Comment: Yes, its 3rd party, You are going to have to import it: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @Ramakrishna I had the same problem with Alamofire for WatchOS. I simply solved it by doing the network stuff on the phone and communicating between them using `WatchConnectivity`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. If you are using NSURLSession, API requests will work just fine

Comment: @Luca so you send the parsed data on the iPhone to iWatch by using WatchConnectivity..

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain why Alamofire is returning this error. It did the same for me.
But it was better, since the WatchOS guidelines say that you can't do long operation on the watch since it's life could be short.

I built a bridge around `WatchConnectivity` where I send message and I reply with the response asynchronously. The only difference is that you need the app on the iPhone is running (not terminated, essentially)